# Enforcing full namespace with using statement in C#

Tags: c#, stylecop

I have been looking around for a while now to see how can I enforce my C# projects to have full namespace path.

For example actual if namespace for class X is `Foo.Bar.Car.Dealer` when doing `Ctrl+.` in visual studio it sometimes puts statement like `using Car.Dealer`; this specially becomes a problem with multiple projects solution. I have been looking around for StyleCop rule or something that might help me get this done.

Any help or ideas?

**EDIT**

The above statement holds true only if the using class falls under same namespace prefix. Here is complete code example:

File: X.cs

```
 namespace Foo.Bar.Car.Dealer {
   class X {}
 }
```

File: UsingClass.cs

```
 namespace Foo.Bar.Another.ClassPath {
  using Car.Dealer;
  class UsingClass {
    private X _x;
  }
 }
```

The VS picked `using Car.Dealer` but I want to enforce using Foo.Bar.Car.Dealer

Comment: Duh I just noticed my question was not complete, so I modified with example.

Comment: It causes namespace conflicts as the solution grows into multiple projects

Comment: Yeah, the problem posed by the original question did not seem to be your real problem :). I do not know, what I could think of is to create code that to append the full namespace to a specific set of classes (say, those marked with a custom attribute of your choice). Like I added in the comment in my "answer"

Comment: `this specially becomes a problem with multiple projects solution.` What kind of problem do you have faced?

Comment: You could potentially [roll your own](https://stylecopplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20Create%20StyleCop%20Custom%20Rule&referringTitle=Documentation).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about versions prior to 2012, but from then on the icon that pops up for action upon coming across an unknown type offers both adding the namespace via using directive or to simply prefix the type being referenced by the full namespace.

If you do not want to add the namespace via using directive (which would look like `using Foo.Bar.Car.Dealer;`),

then in your example you simply need to reference your type `X` as `Foo.Bar.Car.Dealer.X`.

Example:

```
//assuming your X type is instantiable
Foo.Bar.Car.Dealer.X myX = new Foo.Bar.Car.Dealer.X();
```

Comment: I want a compile time rule to enforce this.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a template using T4 for this ? That would go over specific types and, using reflection, append the full namespace to each reference ?

Comment: Again it's always good to enforce things on compile time rather than IDE tools, or template generation.